# embedding more than one youtube video within a website

Tags: javascript, iframe, video, youtube, embed

I am wanting to embed the 5 latest youtube videos in my code, I have used this piece of code but it only displays one:

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=elementanimation" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">   </iframe>
```

How do I edit it so it shows the latest 5? thank you

Comment: it cannot be achieved with one single iframe, try creating a playlist

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an iframe per video like so

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But doing this you'll have to know in advance which video you wanna show, if you want something dynamic you'll have to use php or javascript.